# Sending formData using axios / fetch in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, fetch

From past few days I am trying to send formData using axios / fetch with required headers but the response is network error.

Could anyone please share a code snippet on how to make it work in react native.

Thanks,

### code as follows:

```
 var formdata = new FormData();
 var file = new File([base64Data], "ISDD_" + this.state.fileName, { lastModified: new Date().getMilliseconds() })

    formdata.append("file", file, this.state.fileName);
    formdata.append("folderName", this.state.folderName);
    formdata.append("userName", "myname@gmail.com");
    formdata.append("documents", documents);

  axios({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            // "Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data',
            'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Cache-Control': 'sno-cache',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache'
        },
        data: formdata
    })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(`1 ${response}`)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
```

Comment: Share code of what you have attempted, so we can try to help

Comment: We need more pieces of information like the code and error message you are getting.

Comment: @TravisJames I have added the code, please have a look at it.

Comment: @SathishkumarRakkiasamy i have included my code for the reference, every time i make a api call it throws network error.

Comment: `formdata` should be a FormData object. You should declare it before to append data to it: `const formdata = new FormData(); formdata.append(...)`

Comment: @SylvainF i have already declared it var formdata = new FormData();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var formData = new FormData();  // make sure it is formData not formdata
axios({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        formData
    })
```

Comment: Then you should include that in your code snippet since it is an important part of your question

Comment: While pasting it i missed it out.

Comment: No worries at all!

Comment: Is there any alternative way to achieve it?

Comment: Check your URL and make sure it is correct if you are getting a network error

Comment: Okay I edited my answer with the proper way to send formData.  Try that

Comment: I tried with your approach but its throwing an error Error: Request failed with status code 415

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file", file, this.state.fileName);
    formdata.append("folderName", this.state.folderName);
    formdata.append("userName", "myname@gmail.com");
    formdata.append("documents", documents);

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'url',
    data: formdata,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        //handle success
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        //handle error
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: I tried the above code but to my luck its throwing network error.

Comment: Hey @Shariq, were you able to fix this. for some reason, I am getting "Error:Network Error" with FormData

Comment: @Rajnish sorry for the late reply. Yes I was able to fix it by doing changes on the Backend side. I have faced similar issues earlier also and it got resolved by doing necessary changes on UI side. Can you please elaborate your issue so that I can help to solve you issue.

Comment: Hey @Shariq, thanks for the reply. Though I was able to fix this problem. I was actually submitting an array of Objects, because of which form-data was not able to form  properly. Just had to json_encode the array and receive the data on backend, and decode it back to normal array.